# Find all documents where subdocument is not null

Tags: mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-populate

I have two models, I shorten them for sake of simplicity. I want to get all videos where user is not null.

```
var Video = new mongoose.Schema({    
     user       : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
     status     : {type: String, default: 'Active'},
     recycled   : {type: Number, default: 0}
});

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
     email   : {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
     password: {type: String, select: false},
     status     : {type: String, default: 'Active'},
     recycled   : {type: Number, default: 0}
)};
```

I am doing pagination with sorting and stuff so I used aggregation framework.
I have condition object:

```
var condition   = {
    recycled: {$ne: 1},
    status  : 'Active'
}
```

And so my query looks something like this:

```
var _pageNumber = req.body.pageNumber,
_pageSize   = req.body.limit,

condition   = {
    recycled: {$ne: 1},
    status  : 'Active'
},

var populateQuery = [
    {
        "path": "user",
        model : 'User',
        match : {
            recycled: {$ne: 1}
        }
    }
    // some other models populated...
];

Video.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: condition},
        {$sort: sort},
        {$skip: (_pageNumber > 0 ? ((_pageNumber - 1) * _pageSize) : 0)},
        {$limit: _pageSize}
    ],
    function (err, results) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        Video.populate(results, populateQuery,
            function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;

                return res.status(200).send({
                            message   : 'listOk',
                            videos    : results,
                            pageNumber: _pageNumber
                        });
        )
    });
```

**I TRIED FOLLOWING:**

```
var condition   = {
    recycled: {$ne: 1},
    status  : 'Active',
    'user'  : {$ne: null} or something like 'videos.user'  : {$ne: null}
}
```

But I think videos are not populated with users in that period when the condition is executed and above doesnt work.

**I ALSO TRIED**

```
var populateQuery = [
    {
        "path": "user",
        model : 'User',
        match : {
            recycled     : {$ne: 1},
            "videos.user": {$ne: null}
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the fact that the user is not null directly inside the aggregation match. Also its better for your pagination, because you count only items that are gonna be returned and not ignored videos `user = null`. Don't forget  to retrieve not matching videos due to `user.recycled = 1` for pagination.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT So do you have idea where should I check it? As I already mentioned I tried on some places but without success. The problem I believe is when I remove user, it's ObjectID still remains in Video, so I have to do filtering when population is done. When I get results after aggregate is done I get 2 videos, one with user = model and second one where user = null. I don't want this second one.